# Moving Site has broken CodeIgniter Modules

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I had to move my site to another host and now the codeigniter installation is failing.  I've fixed a few problems, but some of my modules break when I try to save changes.  The end up going to the following url

```
admin/index.php/admin/index.php
```

is that right?

Comment: What modules are you using? What version of CodeIgniter?

Did you change Base URL in config? Also, is the directory structure similar to root like the previous host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the person who had origionally implemented the system had used a differnt  bit of code to get the base script for each module, so I had to go through and change each module.

For the admin module it turned out it was to do with changes in how the two differnt versions of php dealt with paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths are relative. Put before an `/` or write using `base_url()`